# Preventing "apt-file" from updating its database with each "apt update"

Tags: apt, cache, apt-file

Each time I run `apt update` or with the `-m` option(a.k.a `--fix-missing`) I see that  apt-file is trying to update its cache too.I have a slow internet connection and it takes so much to download more than 100MB of `apt-file` caches and when I'm in a hurry this is quite annoying.Is there any way to disable that temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable that temporarily?

To prevent `apt update` from downloading `Contents` files *temporarily*, with `apt-file`’s default configuration, run it as follows:

```
sudo apt -o Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Contents-deb::DefaultEnabled=false update
```

It may be more convenient to revert `apt-file` to its old behaviour, *i.e.* only have it update `Contents` files using `apt-file update` explicitly; to do so, run

```
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh --install
```

See also `/usr/share/doc/apt-file/README.md.gz` on your system for details of the download trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution.There's a file named `50apt-file.conf`(`50` is not important,that's just for taking priorities into account) in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory in ubuntu.

Here's an excerpt of its contents:

```
Acquire::IndexTargets {
...
...
    # Configuration for downloading Contents files for
    # debian-installer packages (udebs).
    deb::Contents-udeb  {
        MetaKey "$(COMPONENT)/Contents-udeb-$(ARCHITECTURE)";
        ShortDescription "Contents-udeb-$(ARCHITECTURE)";
        Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) $(ARCHITECTURE) Contents (udeb)";

        flatMetaKey "Contents-udeb-$(ARCHITECTURE)";
        flatDescription "$(RELEASE) Contents (udeb)";
        KeepCompressed "true";
        PDiffs "true";
        DefaultEnabled "false";
    };
...
...
};
```

Moving that file temporarily to another directory gets the job done.Hope it helps the future readers.

Comment: `sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh --install`

Comment: @nobody Yeah that's a cleaner solution.Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Feel free to change your answer or go to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152885/updating-package-index-is-very-slow-due-to-large-contents-entries  for upvote; we find the solution together.